# VB.net While Loop Never Ends

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I have a meeting registration database. When people register, tblAttendance.RegistrationType gets "W" for Wait List or "F" for Full Registration.

I'm working on a page to move folks from the waiting list to Fill registration.

Here is my chicken scratch for how this should work

1. Get meeting details
2. Create email to be sent
3. lookup event registration to see if there is more capacity than attendees.
4. Lookup folks on the wait list.
5. do while (capacity > attendance) & (there are Folks on waiting list)
   6. move the top person on the waiting list to full registration.
   7. Send them email with connection info for the zoom meeting.

   8. lookup event registration to see if there is more capacity than attendees.
   9. Lookup folks on the wait list.
6. loop

The Code:

```
 Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="offWaitlist.aspx.vb" Inherits="Parish_Faith_Formation.offWaitlist" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>
    <%
        Response.Write("Meeting: " & Request.QueryString("meeting") & "<br><br>")
        
        Dim connetionString As String
        connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim sql As String
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim dsOpenings As New DataSet
        Dim dsWaitingList As New DataSet
        Dim dsMeetings As New DataSet
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand()
        
        ' 1. get meeting details.
        sql = "SELECT tblmeeting.* FROM tblmeeting WHERE (((tblmeeting.ID)=" & Request.QueryString("meeting") & "));"
        command.CommandText = sql
        command.Connection = connection
      
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dsMeetings)
        
        '2. create email body.
        Session("body") = ""
        Session("body") = Session("body") & " <!DOCTYPE HTML >"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & " <html><head>"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & " <meta charset=""utf-8"">"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & " <meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge"" />"


        Session("body") = Session("body") & " <title>RCDA.org Custom Applications</title>"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & " <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"">"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<script>            "
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "header{"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "display:block;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "height:30px; "
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "line-height:30px;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "background-color:#3B4A83;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "/*background-color:#2C5463;*/"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "width:85%;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "margin:auto;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "text-align:center;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "color:#fff;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "font-family:arial;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "font-size:14pt;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "vertical-align:middle;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "min-width:350px;"
    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "   box-shadow: -5px 20px 18px #A0A0A0, 5px 20px 18px #A0A0A0, -5px 0px 18px #A0A0A0, 5px 0px 18px #A0A0A0;"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "}"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "article{"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "width:85%;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "margin:0 auto;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "vertical-align:top;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "/*background-color:#ffffff;*/"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "background-color:#fff;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "padding:0; "
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "min-height: calc(100% - 30px) !important;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "min-width:350px;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "flex: 1 0 auto; "
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "   "
    
    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #808080;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "/* For IE 8 */"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "box-shadow: 10px 15px 18px rgba(128, 128, 128, .7), -10px 15px 18px rgba(128, 128, 128, .7); "
    
    
    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "}"


    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "html, body{"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "height:98%;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "background-color:#CCC;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "min-width:300px;"
    
    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "}  "
    

        Session("body") = Session("body") & ".arial10pt{"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "font-family: arial;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "font-size:10pt;"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "}"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</script>"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</head>"
  
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<body >"
 
     
     
     


        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<header  style=""width:85%; margin:0 auto; box-shadow: -5px 20px 18px #A0A0A0, 5px 20px 18px #A0A0A0, -5px 0px 18px #A0A0A0, 5px 0px 18px #A0A0A0;  overflow:visible; background-color:#394984; color:#fff;"" >"
  

       
           
    
    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</header>"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<article style=""border:1px;#aaaaaa solid;"" > "
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<div style=""width:87%; margin:0 auto;""><br>"
        
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<div style=""width:40%; margin:0 auto;"">"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<br /><br /> "
    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "Thank you for registering for: <strong>" & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("meetingName") & " <br>on " & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Occurrence") & "</strong><br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<br />"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<strong>Join Zoom Meeting: </strong><a href=""" & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("URL") & """>" & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("URL") & "</a><br />"


        Session("body") = Session("body") & "Password: " & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("password") & "        <br />"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "        <br><strong>One tap mobile</strong><br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+16465588656,,687241195# US (New York)<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+13126266799,,687241195# US (Chicago)<br />"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<br />"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<strong>Dial by your location</strong><br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+1 646 558 8656 US (New York)<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+1 312 626 6799 US (Chicago)<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+1 301 715 8592 US<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+1 346 248 7799 US (Houston)<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+1 669 900 9128 US (San Jose)<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "+1 253 215 8782 US<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "Meeting ID: " & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("meetingID") & "<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<br />"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "Find your local number: <a href=""https://zoom.us/u/arsh7lTr5"">https://zoom.us/u/arsh7lTr5</a>"

    
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</div>"

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "<br><br></div> "

        If Session("payment") = "check" Then
            Session("body") = Session("body") & "<div class=""arial10pt"" style=""text-align:center;"">You indicated that you intend to pay by check.<br /> Please mail your check for $" & dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("cost") & " to: <br /><br />Office of Lay Ministry and Parish Faith Formation<br />40 N. Main Ave<br />Albany, NY 12203</div>"
        End If
        
        If Session("payment") = "paypal" Then
            Session("body") = Session("body") & "<div class=""arial10pt"" style=""text-align:center;"">Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you. You may log into your account at <a href=""http://www.paypal.com"">www.paypal.com</a> to view details of this transaction confirming your purchase.</div>"
        End If
        
        If Session("payment") = "College Students Free" Then
            Session("body") = Session("body") & "<div class=""arial10pt"" style=""text-align:center;"">As a college student, you have been invited to attend this meeting for free. Enjoy!<br /><br /></div>"
        End If
        
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</article>"

                

        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</body>"
        Session("body") = Session("body") & "</html>   "
        
        
           
        
        
        '3. lookup to see if there are any openings.
        sql = "SELECT tblmeeting.ID, tblmeeting.Capacity, Count(tblAttendance.Registrant_ID) AS Attendance FROM tblmeeting INNER JOIN tblAttendance ON tblmeeting.ID = tblAttendance.Meeting_ID GROUP BY tblmeeting.ID, tblmeeting.Capacity HAVING (((tblmeeting.ID)=" & Request.QueryString("meeting") & "));"
        command.CommandText = sql
        command.Connection = connection
        
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dsOpenings)
        
        Response.Write("Capacity: " & dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("capacity") & "<br>")
        Response.Write("Attendance: " & dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("attendance") & "<br>")
        
        If (dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("capacity") > dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("attendance")) = True Then
            Response.Write("there are openings!<br>")
        Else
            Response.Write("there are NO openings!<br>")
        End If
        
        '-----------------------------------------------------------
        '4. lookup to see if there are people on the waiting list.
        sql = "SELECT tblAttendance.ID, tblAttendance.Meeting_ID, tblAttendance.Registrant_ID AS Attendance, tblAttendance.RegistrationType, tblAttendance.RegistrationDate, tblRegistrants.Fname, tblRegistrants.Lname, tblRegistrants.Email FROM tblRegistrants INNER JOIN tblAttendance ON tblRegistrants.ID = tblAttendance.Registrant_ID WHERE (((tblAttendance.Meeting_ID)=" & Request.QueryString("meeting") & ") AND ((tblAttendance.RegistrationType)='W')) ORDER BY tblAttendance.RegistrationDate;"
        command.CommandText = sql
        command.Connection = connection
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dsWaitingList)
        If dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Session("email") = dsWaitingList
        End If
        If dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Response.Write("There are people on the waiting list!<br><br>")
        Else
            Response.Write("There are NO people on the waiting list!<br><br>")
        End If
       
        '5. Loop
        Do While ((dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("capacity") > dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("attendance")) And dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0)
            Response.Write("Processing the next person (" & dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("lname") & ", " & dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("fname") & ") off the waiting list.<br><br>")
            
                   
            '6. move the person into full registration
            sql = "UPDATE tblAttendance SET tblAttendance.RegistrationType = 'F', tblAttendance.RegistrationDate = getdate() WHERE (((tblAttendance.ID)=" & dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("id") & "));"
            Response.Write("<br><br>" & sql & "<br><br>")
            command.CommandText = sql
            command.Connection = connection
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Session("sendEmail") = 0
            
            
            '7.send email
            
           
            
            Dim mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            
            mail.To.Add(dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("email"))
            
            mail.Subject = dsMeetings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("MeetingName")
            
            mail.Body = Session("body")

            Dim dsMailServer As New DataSet
            sql = "SELECT tblSMTPServer.* FROM MailServer.dbo.tblSMTPServer WHERE (((tblSMTPServer.ID)=1));"
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(dsMailServer)
            
            Session("smtpClient") = dsMailServer.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("SMTPClient")
            Session("port") = dsMailServer.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("port")
            Session("UserName") = "username@company.org"
            Session("Password") = "password"
            Session("Domain") = dsMailServer.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("domain")
            Session("ssl") = dsMailServer.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("SSL")
            
            
            
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(Session("SMTPClient"))
            smtp.Port = 587
            
            mail.From = New MailAddress(Session("username"))
           

            mail.To.Add("registrant@email.org")
            mail.ReplyTo = New MailAddress("username@company.org")
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Session("username"), Session("password"), Session("domain"))
            If Session("SSL") = -1 Then
                smtp.EnableSsl() = True
            Else
                smtp.EnableSsl() = False
            End If
            If Session("sendEmail") = 0 Then
                smtp.Send(mail)
                Session("sendEmail") = 1
            End If
            
            
            
            '8. lookup to see if there are any openings.
            sql = "SELECT tblmeeting.ID, tblmeeting.Capacity, Count(tblAttendance.Registrant_ID) AS Attendance FROM tblmeeting INNER JOIN tblAttendance ON tblmeeting.ID = tblAttendance.Meeting_ID GROUP BY tblmeeting.ID, tblmeeting.Capacity HAVING (((tblmeeting.ID)=" & Request.QueryString("meeting") & "));"
            command.CommandText = sql
            command.Connection = connection
        
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(dsOpenings)
        
            Response.Write("Capacity: " & dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("capacity") & "<br>")
            Response.Write("Attendance: " & dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("attendance") & "<br>")
        
            If (dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("capacity") > dsOpenings.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("attendance")) = True Then
                Response.Write("there are openings!<br>")
            Else
                Response.Write("there are NO openings!<br>")
            End If
        
            
            '9. lookup to see if there are people on the waiting list.
            sql = "SELECT tblAttendance.ID, tblAttendance.Meeting_ID, tblAttendance.Registrant_ID AS Attendance, tblAttendance.RegistrationType, tblAttendance.RegistrationDate, tblRegistrants.Fname, tblRegistrants.Lname FROM tblRegistrants INNER JOIN tblAttendance ON tblRegistrants.ID = tblAttendance.Registrant_ID WHERE (((tblAttendance.Meeting_ID)=" & Request.QueryString("meeting") & ") AND ((tblAttendance.RegistrationType)='W')) ORDER BY tblAttendance.RegistrationDate;"
            command.CommandText = sql
            command.Connection = connection
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(dsWaitingList)
            
            If dsWaitingList.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Response.Write("There are people on the waiting list!<br>")
            Else
                Response.Write("There are NO people on the waiting list!<br>")
            End If
           
            
           
        '10. loop    
        Loop
            
        connection.Close()

            %>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

To try and get this to work, I swapped out the do while loop for an if statement and it ran perfectly fine for one person. I know it ran fine because I put a ton of screen writes in & verified the data in the table afterwards.

With the loop, the browser spins and never finishes. I get no screen output either. I did try commenting out the email send command so I could rule out the sending as causing the delay.

Comment: Oh hey cool, SQL injection risk in step 9'. What did you say this website is for?

Comment: as far as I can see you don't have anything in the loop that modifies `dsOpenings`, so the condition being compared against never changes. However rarely have I seen code that is this hard to follow.

Comment: Unrelated to your while loop woes, consider using a templating engine for these sorts of boilerplate HTML emails in the future. They make a horrible task slightly less Sisyphean.

Comment: Either break on the first line inside the `While` loop (or log, print, etc) and check your condition values because most likely they are not changing, or at least are - obviously - not satisfying your exit condition. Also, try to post less convoluted code; a minimal example is clearer and, while creating that, you'll possibly find your problem.

Comment: #8 gets the registration capacity of the meeting and the number of registered folks for the meeting. With every pass of the loop someone is moved from the wait list to full registration so the number of registered folks should grow. but it doesn't because I didn't specify where RegistrationType="F". Thanks for catching this Tom.

Comment: You are only using Rows(0), don't you want a row counter in there?

Comment: nope, no row counter. I get all the folks on the waiting list and only move row 0 to full registration then loop. Row 0 is sorted as earliest on the waiting list. The next row 0 is moved to full registration next pass...loop...loop.

Comment: That is too many strings to be creating and throwing away for Session("body"). Use a `StringBuilder` (which is mutable) to build your string.

Comment: I fixed #9 to be a parameterized query and it all works. A new problem has emerged:  when I try to edit records that were modified using VB.net, I get the following error: The data has been changed.Another user edited the record before you attempted to save your record. The issue appears in SQL server where the table resides and in the linked access table. what gives? I checked and I am closing the connection after looping. Replacing the records with new ones does not solve the problem.

Comment: Why the DataSet and DataAdapter? Why not just use Command and DataTable?

Comment: Can you break up the monolith into logical Subs and Functions?

Comment: That's how I've always done it. Can you explain Command and DataTable?

Comment: subs and functions?

Comment: I just noticed that the queries in the loop are not updating the datasets correctly. I put one person on the waiting list and after they are moved to full registration, the queries are rerun but do not show the change in registration amount or that there are no longer folks on the waiting list. This is why my loop never ends. I verified this using an if statement instead. I did find that if I reloaded the page, I saw the new expected query values.  I determined that I need to close the connection in order to get new values.

Comment: By the way, it's not just query #9 that is vulnerable, *all* your queries should use parameters instead of injected user-values

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

1. In the loop, #8, I forgot to look at attendance as people with tblAttendance.RegisrtationType="F". I was grabbing all registered people since I left out part of the where clause. Thus the attendance number never changed. This would cause the loop to never execute since under normal circumstances the query would never see max capacity greater than attendance.
2. After fixing my queries in the loop, I learned that I needed to close the connection to the SQL server and reopen it in order for the DataSets to update properly #8 & #9.

After these 2 changes, the loop executed as expected.

Comment: If this is the answer you can mark it with the green check mark to close the question out. This will stop people from coming to try to help.